# Install xdotool on non-standard, very old PC, without root/sudo

Tags: cross-compiling, redhat, xdotool

I have to work with some old PC (with some old Fedora, I think), my work is mainly to click custom button few thousand times. It can be easily simulated with xdotool, but either I don't have root access (so /dev/input/mice is forbidden for me) and I don't have libraries for xdotool. This PC does not even have **yum** command! So I ask, is there a simple way to precompile xdotool program with some -static option for old Intel processor, or include every needed library inside main program folder?

Comment: Have you tried just running the binary file `xdotool` found in a RPM package? You can find a package in https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=xdotool, download it from your browser, open it with an archive manager such as `ark`, transfer the file `xdotool` to your server.